# User Input match using regular expression in python

Tags: python

```
import re
path ='C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\name.txt'
shakes = open(path, 'r')
love = open("store.txt", "w")

for line in shakes:
    if re.match("**(.*)(P|P)ython(.*)**", line):
        print >> store, line,
```

In the above example i have used "Python" as the text to be searched. But i need the user to input the word and search.

For example :

```
import re
book=input("Enter the book name")
path ='C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\name.txt'
shakes = open(path, 'r')
love = open("store.txt", "w")

for line in shakes:
    if re.match(book, line):
        print >> store, line,
```

This program is running and asking "Enter the book name", when the book name is entered(eg : digital), it is returning error stating `name 'digital' is not defined.`

Help with this.

How to get a string from the user and search it in the file to find the match.

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input` as the latter attempts to evaluate the input as Python code.

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or python 3? In python 2.7, use ``raw_input` instead of `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using python 2.7

In python 2.7 use `raw_input` instead of `input`.
If you used input then it will throw error.

```
book=raw_input("Enter the book name")
```

Please let me know if the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

You're directly substituting the variable in your regex. Instead of that try doing:

```
if re.match("**(.*)"+book+"(.*)**", line):
```

And, also use `raw_input` for `input` function in `book=input("Enter the book name")`